# How can I use Codeigniter 3 validation library in other framework

Tags: validation, zend-framework2, codeigniter-3

I want to develop API in ZF2 framework and I want to use CodeIgniter 3 validation [library](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#setting-rules-using-an-array) for validate API request parameters. So is it possible or not. If possible so how can I do it. Suggest any solutions please.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is no. You can't use it in Zend or any other framework.

Form validation library of the Codeigniter is actually not a library, its [just a god object](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/libraries/Form_validation.php) which is tightly coupled to the framework's itself. It also contains multiple bad practices such as using global function calls, not respecting PSR standards and breaking multiple object oriented design principles.

I strongly recommend to use [zend-inputfilter](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-inputfilter) component. You can easily validate and sanitize any kind of incoming data using it.